# python dict is getting overwritten in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following code that I am trying to create a nested dictionary with. For some reason in my for loop where I have the following code `ap_dict[ap_name][cur_efr][i] = {}` this keeps getting overwritten and whatever the last number in my loop is the only value that remains in the dictionary.

Here is my full code with loops

```
ap_dict = {}
efr_data_list = [412690]
ap_names_list = ['L2']
for ap_name in ap_names_list:
    ap_dict[ap_name] = {}
    for cur_efr in efr_data_list:
        for ap in range(0, len(data['data']['stats'])):
            print('ap is {}'.format(ap))
            if data['data']['stats'][ap]['name'] == ap_name:
                a = len(data['data']['stats'][ap]['runs'])
                print('a is {}'.format(a))
                for i in range(0, len(data['data']['stats'][ap]['runs'])):
                    ap_dict[ap_name][cur_efr] = {}
                    ap_dict[ap_name][cur_efr][i] = {}
                    print('ap_dict is {}'.format(ap_dict))
```

This is what i see when the loop is in progress and is actually what I am trying to achive

```
ap_dict is {'L2': {412690: {0: {}}}}
ap_dict is {'L2': {412690: {1: {}}}}
ap_dict is {'L2': {412690: {2: {}}}}
ap_dict is {'L2': {412690: {3: {}}}}
ap_dict is {'L2': {412690: {4: {}}}}
ap_dict is {'L2': {412690: {5: {}}}}
```

This is what remains in the dict after  the loop is complete

```
>>> ap_dict
    {'L2': {412690: {5: {}}}}
```

Comment: Please give us an example of your desired output. The way you assign to your dictionary is the problem but without proper output example we can't really help you to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                for i in range(0, len(data['data']['stats'][ap]['runs'])):
                ap_dict[ap_name][cur_efr] = {} # Move this line to above for
                ap_dict[ap_name][cur_efr][i] = {}
                print('ap_dict is {}'.format(ap_dict))
```

This line is setting `ap_dict[ap_name][cur_efr]` to empty map in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
ap_dict[ap_name][cur_efr] = {}
```

should be moved to appear just **before** the `for i in range` loop (currently it is appearing just **inside** that loop)